# using orbot bridges on android

Tags: bridge, orbot, android

when using the bridge through Google, azzure, or Amazon i get errors like the below.

NOTICE: Bridge at '0.0.2.0:1' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Skipping.

is there any idea why i get  this or is it a bug?

thanks,
Msadek

Answer (score 1):

This may be considered a bug, an unfortunately collision between `FirewallPorts`, `ReachableAddresses`, `FascistFirewall` and the spoofed destination address of the `Meek` protocol.

If you have configured Orbot to only pick guards to specific ports or addresses, then you should remove those settings as a work around to be able to use `Meek`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different IPtables - it's in options of Orbot. And also - via teminal - check telnet connectivity to the bridge

Comment: the problem is that the ip shown in log is fake and is the same for the three cloud providers Google, amazon and azure.

Comment: @msadek I see - but try to elaborate IPTables option in settings. Is it working? Change it and make a full reboot for a clean experiment